# Error when getting the image：Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Any]' with an index of type 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey'

Tags: swift

I am trying to get a photo from the system album and using below code:

```swift
public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

//        var image: UIImage? = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage.rawValue] as? UIImage

        guard var image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else { return }

//        var image = info.index(forKey: UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage.rawValue) as? UIImage

        if (image == nil ) {
//            image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
            image = info.index(forKey: UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage.rawValue) as? UIImage
        }
```

But the xcode always warns me：

> “Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Any]' with an index of
>   type 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey'”

I don't know how to change to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method signature. It should be similar to this,

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, 
           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        guard let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else { return }

    }
```

Comment: Can you show your code that you tried?

Comment: Did you notice any difference in the method signatures?

Comment: There is a difference between `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any])` and `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {` in your and above method signatures. Please compare carefully.